# How to tell when a Word comment is added

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my Word document, I want to turn on Protection after the user enters a comment. I need a way to tell when the  new comment has been added so I can run the aDocument.Protect command.

If this were Excel, I could put in a `Worksheet_Change` macro that keeps track of the number of comments. But there is no `Document_Change` in Word.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Word does indeed have a 'DocumentChange' event, though a 'WindowSelectionChange' event may be more applicable to your needs. See: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/AppClassEvents.htm